# How to concatenate columns in CSV file using Python and Count the Total per UniqueID?

Tags: python, csv, hyperlink, concatenation

This question have been asked multiple times in this community but I couldn't find the correct answers since I am beginner in Python. I got 2 questions actually:

1. I want to concatenate 3 columns (A,B,C) with its value into 1 Column. Header would be ABC.

import os
import pandas as pd

directory = 'C:/Path'
ext = ('.csv')

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
f = os.path.join(directory, filename)

```
if f.endswith(ext):

    head_tail = os.path.split(f)
    head_tail1 = 'C:/Output'
    k =head_tail[1]
    r=k.split(".")[0]

    p=head_tail1 + "/" + r + " - Revised.csv"

    mydata = pd.read_csv(f)

    new =mydata[["A","B","C","D"]]
    new = new.rename(columns={'D': 'Total'})
    new['Total'] = 1
    new.to_csv(p ,index=False)
```

2. Once concatenated, is it possible to count the uniqueid and put the total in Column D? Basically, to get the total count per uniqueid (Column ABC),the data can be found on a link when you click that UniqueID. For ex: Column ABC - uniqueid1, -> click -> go to the next page, total of that uniqueid.

On the link page, you can get the total numbers of uniqueid by Serial ID

I have no idea how to do this, but I would really appreciate if someone can help me on this project and would learn a lot from this.

Thank you very much. God Bless

Searched in Google, Youtube and Stackoverflow, couldn't find the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry your question is formulated in a very unclear way. For the first part, it seems like you are looking for [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html). The second part could be solved with [pandas.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). But it is not clear to me why you can't directly sum up the A, B, C columns in the original dataframe.

Comment: Apologies and thank you for answering my question. First question is to concatenate 3 columns A B C and have it 1 column with header name ABC. I'm trying your https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html but not sure which one to use.

Comment: Second question is to get the total of parts from a website. For security purposes, I cannot share the company link. Basically, get that total on the page and put that in Column D of my CSV file. For Example: Column ABC that is concatenated with data Uniqueid1. The total of that  Uniqueid1 will write in Column D. Sorry, its too complicated I wish I can show you my screen but I can't :) Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your question correctly. However, if you know exactly the column names (e.g., `A`, `B`, and `C`) that you want to concatenate you can do something like code below.

`''.join(merge_columns)` is to concatenate column names.

`new[merge_columns].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)` is to concatenate their values.

Then, you can count unique values of the new column using `groupby().count()`.

```
new = mydata[["A","B","C","D"]]
new = new.rename(columns={'D': 'Total'})
new['Total'] = 1

# added lines
merge_columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
merged_col = ''.join(merge_columns)
new[merged_col] = new[merge_columns].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
new.drop(merge_columns, axis=1, inplace=True)
new = new.groupby(merged_col).count().reset_index()

new.to_csv(p ,index=False)
```

example:

```
# before

>     new

   A  B  C  Total
0  a  b  c      1
1  x  y  z      1
2  a  b  c      1

# after execute added lines

>     new

   ABC  Total
0  abc      2
1  xyz      1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response and the added lines work. However, I wanted to put a dot on each values that were concatenated. Result should be:        ABC       Total
0  a.b.c      2
1  x.y.z      1

Comment: `lambda x: ''.join(x)` --> `lambda x: '.'.join(x)`

Comment: lambda x: '.'.join(x) thank you :) I just need to put a dot hahaha I'm learning so much from you.

Comment: Hi @JayPeerachai, quick question if I may, with merge_columns and groupby function, is there a limitation on data records in csv or excel? 1 csv file with 143 records 785kb in size, the script works fine but on big file like 46,276 records 10,013kb in size, the script doesn't function anymore. it doesn't concatenate the 3 columns and groupby doesn't work anymore. Any input is highly appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure about the root of your problem but I think the limitation of any computation mostly depends on the memory (RAM) rather than the backend of the groupby function.

Comment: Issue resolved in my other question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Next time, try to specify your issues and give a minimal reproducible example.
This is just an example how to use pd.melt and pd.groupby.
I hope it helps with your question.

```
import pandas as pd

### example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([['first', 1, 2, 3], ['second', 4, 5, 6], ['third', 7, 8, 9]], columns=['ID', 'A', 'B', 'C'])

### directly sum up A, B and C
df['total'] = df.sum(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
print(df)

### how to create a so called long dataframe with melt
df_long = pd.melt(df, id_vars='ID', value_vars=['A', 'B', 'C'], var_name='ABC')
print(df_long)

### group long dataframe by column and sum up all values with this ID
df_group = df_long.groupby(by='ID').sum()
print(df_group)
```

Comment: thank you for providing samples and I really appreciate you assisting me on this. On the concatenate code, below is my script and having an issue:                                                       new =mydata[["A","B","C","D"]]
        new = new.rename(columns={'D': 'Total Parts'})
        new['Total Parts'] = 1
        df_long = pd.melt(df, id_vars='ID', value_vars=['A', 'B', 'C'], var_name='ABC')
        print(df_long)
        new.to_csv(p ,index=False)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Project.py", line 25, in <module>
    df_long = pd.melt(df, id_vars='ID', value_vars=['A', 'B', 'C'], var_name='ABC')
NameError: name 'df' is not defined. Did you mean: 'f'?

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: df is just the name of the dataframe i created. You have to change it accordingly to your code.